# How are javascript libraries available when wrapped in an IIFE? Isn't the execution context disposed?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, iife

In the Underscore js library all the code is wrapped inside:

```
(function() {  
     //rest of library etc.
}.call(this));
```

I understand wrapping the function() in () is for namespace purposes, and that the .call(this) invokes the library on startup passing the window object.

But my understanding is that once an execution context has finished running it is 'deleted'. So how is all of the code inside this library available to other script files?

Question has been answered but it has brought up this question in my head:

This makes sense to me now. The function is executed and attaches its library onto the window object. 
However, when using this approach libraries can overwrite each other if they attach the same object name to the window object.

Would it not be preferable to do something like:

```
var library1 = function(
     var func1 = function(){ 

     }; 
  return { 
     func1: func1 
  })(this);
```

Comment: It modifies global state, e.g. `window.myNamespace = { stuff }`. The 'stuff' will still have access to the execution context of the IIFE because of lexical closure (even though nothing else does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This concept can be explained here with a simple example:

```
//library code starts
(function(){

    this.hello = function(){
        console.log("asd");
    }

}).call(this);
//library code ends


//outside the library
//will print the function showing that it is available outside the library
console.log(window.hello); //will print the function
console.log(hello); 

//will console.log hello
hello();
```

Since call function calls the IIFE with this (which points to window object), even if you want to get the value of window object outside the library code you can get that easily.

Since **hello** function is binded to window object it is available to be called outside the library code.

This applies to any function or variable bound to the window object.

**Understanding the execution context**

The execution context is only made when a particular function is called or some variable/ object is being used.

For each called function, a different execution context is made which is disposed off when the execution finishes. That does not mean the object (window) in this case will not be a part of the memory any more.

You may call a function 10 times with different arguments and it will create 10 different execution contexts assigning memory at runtime and destroying it once the execution is completed. It has nothing to do with the library code being loaded.

Comment: This makes sense to me now. The function is executed and attaches its library onto the window object. 

However, when using this approach libraries can overwrite each other if they attach the same object name to the window object.

Would it not be preferable to do something like:

var library1 = function(

  var func1 = function(){
  };

return {
func1: func1
}

)(this);

Comment: @JackClark It would make no difference; `library1` is exposed exactly the same way.